# What is returned when calling emptyStack.top()

Tags: c++, types, stack

When calling `stack.top()` with an empty stack, what exactly is returned (value, type, etc)?

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    stack<char> thing;
    sometype topChar = thing.top();
    cout << topChar << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there something preventing you from consulting some documentation? A firewall or something like that?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/back

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit note that i said "empty" stack. i am asking what is returned when a last element does not exist. the docs you linked don't say what happens.

Comment: Yes, they do. Read closer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`top` returns a reference. It is equivalent to calling the underlying container's `back` method. As you might expect when trying to get a reference to something that doesn't exist, the result is undefined.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), when discussing undefined behavior states:

> there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program

In other words, anything can happen, so you should avoid using `top` on an empty container. Always make sure the container is not empty when using `top`.

Comment: Extra bit of info, from the same site, "Calling back on an empty container is undefined." (Where `top` is the stack equivalent of `back`, and the documentation for top refers to back.)